# Minimal vs. Non-minimal coupling in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, lagrangian-formalism, gauge-theory, qft-in-curved-spacetime

What is the difference between Minimal vs. Non-minimal coupling in General Relativity? A brief introduction to [Minimal Coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_coupling) in General Relativity could be useful too.

Comment: I think its best to not get to caught up in this question in the specific context of GR. That is, look at the question in the more general context of gauge theories and effective field theory. For a discussion, see the reference: http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.0017

Comment: There are many reasons as why should consider non-minimal coupling. they are discussed in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0002091v2.pdf)

Answer (score 14):

I'll give as example the case of a scalar field. We assume the Einstein-Hilbert action:
\begin{equation}
S_{\text{grav}}=\int d^4x\ \sqrt{|g|}R
\end{equation}
Now, we would like to consider a quantum field in the spacetime:
$$S=S_{\text{grav}}+S_{\text{matter}}+S_{\text{coupling}}$$
To first order in the curvature, the only scalar that couples gravity and the quantum field, which we can build out of a scalar field $\phi$ and curvature-related tensor objects, is $R \phi^2$. In general, there will be higher order terms if one considers higher energies. We will take the standard Lagrangian for a scalar field. The total action is now
\begin{equation}
S=\int d^4x \sqrt{|g|}\bigl(R+\frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\nu}\nabla_\mu\phi\nabla_\nu\phi+(m^2+\xi R)\phi^2\bigr)
\end{equation}
Where $\xi$ is the coupling constant. Minimal coupling amounts to setting $\xi=0$. As you can imagine, this is the simplest (and perhaps most natural?) case. Another reasonably popular choice seems to be $\xi=\frac{1}{6}$. In this case, we say that the field is *conformally* coupled to gravity, because the action is now invariant under conformal transformations of the metric:
$$ g_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow \Omega^2(x)g_{\mu\nu}$$
Any possible $\xi\neq 0$ is a case of non-minimal coupling. Basically, minimal coupling means avoiding introducing any extra terms in the action.

Comment: Danu, could please explain the difference between setting $\xi=0$ and $\xi\neq0$

Comment: Well, obviously the difference is whether the field directly couples to gravity or not.

Comment: Donu, What is the physical interpretation for a field to directly couple to gravity.

Comment: Danu, the coupling that one usually finds in these non-minimally coupled inflation models is $R\phi^2$ and not $R\phi$ (see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-minimally_coupled_inflation)). Is that what you meant? And if yes, why does one not consider the linear field coupling to the Ricci scalar, can it be absorbed somehow?

Comment: @physicus You're absolutely right! I think a linear coupling would probably yield a pathological theory because the classical Hamiltonian seems to be unbounded from below. It is also wholly possible that a linear term such as this can be made to disappear through a field redefinition somehow, although I don't immediately see how.

Comment: So, how a linear coupling like the one is [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.08732v2.pdf) yield a pathological theory?

Comment: How to understand this? That the field does not interact with the gravitational field in any way, or is this interaction so small that it can be neglected? After all, if the field has energy-momentum, it must interact gravitationally.