# What is the difference between the non-minimal coupling of GR to a scalar field and the coupling of the metric to the stress tensor?

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, action, interactions

In General Relativity we can non-minimally couple the action of the gravitational field to a scalar field, as seen [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/103892/215076), where the lowest order gravitational action is coupled to the scalar fields with the form: $\kappa R\phi^2$.

In linearized gravity it is assumed that the gravitational field couples to the stress tensor and not directly to the field $\phi$, with the form $\kappa h_{\mu\nu}T^{\mu\nu}$, as seen [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/581389/215076).

What is the difference between coupling directly to the field $\phi$ vs the stress tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$?

In the linearized case, why do we not take the coupling directly with $\phi$ as $\kappa h\phi ^2$, where $h=h^{\mu}_{\mu}=\eta^{\mu\nu}h_{\mu\nu}$ instead?

Comment: Minimal coupling means you *don't* have $\kappa R \phi^2$.

Comment: oops sorry let me correct the question

Answer (score 0):

Since $\frac{\partial R}{\partial g_{\mu\nu}} \neq 0$, the Hilbert procedure yields a stress tensor for a scalar field which depends on the coefficient of $R\phi^2$. This is the only thing that makes the two cases differ.

The minimally coupled system linearizes to an action where $h_{\mu\nu}$ multiplies the stress tensor for a scalar without $R\phi^2$. The non-minimally coupled system linearizes to an action where $h_{\mu\nu}$ multiplies the stress tensor for a scalar with $R\phi^2$.

It's true that $R\phi^2$ is not the only way of making the coupling between a scalar and gravity non-minimal. But every time I see one of these being used, the combination of $\phi$ and curvature invariants is written explicitly. If an author actually wrote
\begin{equation}
\int \left ( \frac{1}{2\kappa} R + \mathcal{L}_M  + g_{\mu\nu} T^{\mu\nu} \right ) \sqrt{-g} \, dx
\end{equation}
where $T^{\mu\nu}$ is the thing that would've been the matter stress tensor before $g_{\mu\nu} T^{\mu\nu}$ was added, this would be very confusing. Because this would be equivalent to just rescaling the potential in $\mathcal{L}_M$.